# What is the meaning of the sentence: Do you want to weigh in on this?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I work in a project team. This was a question I was asked:

> Do you want to weigh in on this?

What does this mean?

How should I answer correctly?

Comment: *Weigh in* means add your view to a discussion. It could be easily googled though. Also, try [ell.se] for questions regarding learning English.

Comment: We were able to find three dictionaries which list *weigh in (with)* with a relevant meaning: Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English, Macmillan Dictionary, and Oxford Phrasal Verbs.  But none of them, interestingly, list *weigh in (on)*.

Answer (score 5):

Weirdly enough, although Christine Ammer, *The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms* (1997) has entries for "weigh in" ("Be weighed; also, be of a particular weight") and "weigh on" ("Depress"), it says nothing about "weigh in on." So I guess this isn't a general reference idiom.

Nevertheless, it is an idiom, and it has become much more popular since about 1980 than it was prior to that, as this Ngram chart for the period 1860–2005 indicates:

[image].

The sense of the idiom is something like "express an opinion about [something]." but it may have originated as an idea along the lines of "throw one's weight [behind one person, party, or viewpoint in a controversy]."

I was mildly surprised to see that *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language* (2011) defines the phrase in truncated form as "weigh in" and attaches that phrase to *with*, not *on* in the illustrative example it provides:

> **weigh in 1.** *Sports* To be weighed at a weigh-in. **2.** To have one's baggage weighed, as at an airport. **3.** To be of a specified weight: *The new book weighs in at 7 pounds*. **4.** *Slang* To join in a discussion; utter a remark: *She weighed in with some pertinent facts*.

But this makes sense: *AHDEL* simply chose to focus on how the person in the example weighed in ("with some pertinent facts") rather than on where she weighed in ("on the issue of administrative incompetence," say).

The earliest Google Books matches for "weigh in on [a subject]" are quite recent. From Kenneth Mead, [National Highway System: Refinements Would Strengthen the System](https://books.google.com/books?id=6zQpAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA9&dq=%22weigh+in+on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5mZjwiK3RAhVI-mMKHQHsBqU4ChDoAQgyMAU#v=onepage&q=%22weigh%20in%20on%22&f=false) (1994):

> Furthermore, the establishment of consistent, broader NHS linkages to other transportation modes may be postponed possibly until 2 years after NHS enactment, or be accomplished as part of the development of the National Transportation System. Acceptance of such a delay could mean that the Congress may not have the opportunity to **weigh in on** the criteria established and the resulting outcomes of NHS connections to other modes of transportation and major travel destinations.

From Susan Douglas, [*Where the Girls Are: Growing Up Female With the Mass Media*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hyCP94EAb3kC&pg=PA195&dq=%22weigh+in+on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ6fW1ia3RAhUNy2MKHT16C104FBDoAQgwMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22weigh%20in%20on%22&f=false) (1995):

> But ABC couldn't even let this level of fulmination lie. Harry [Reasoner] apparently got his colleague Howard K. Smith so exercised that the next night he, too, had to **weigh in on** the women's movement. "Among the multitude of causes in this cause-ridden age, one that has not, to me at least, made its case is women's lib," he began, echoing his line at the time of the Women's Strike for Equality.

From Daryl Hafter, [*European Women and Preindustrial Craft*](https://books.google.com/books?id=WvypbRXZVDAC&pg=PA132&dq=%22weigh+in+on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5mZjwiK3RAhVI-mMKHQHsBqU4ChDoAQgoMAM#v=onepage&q=%22weigh%20in%20on%22&f=false) (1995):

> You are signaling something about your philosophy of government or, in elections tht focus on a single issue, your opinion on that issue. More fundamentally, you are confirming your belief that it's *worth* voting—that you value a system that offers its citizens the chance to **weigh in on** the candidates and the issues of the day.

From Harvey Fineberg, [*Society's Choices: Social and Ethical Decision Making in Biomedicine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=R16dAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT353&dq=%22weigh+in+on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF0oOOiK3RAhUN8GMKHbGeAO4Q6AEINDAF#v=onepage&q=%22weigh%20in%20on%22&f=false) (1995):

> The United States is a highly diverse and complicated society. Many groups **"weigh in" on** significant health policy issues. America's expansive range of policymaking bodies and groups seeking to influence policy render it impossible to offer a systematic and comprehensive analysis of health policy formulation.

From John Gould, [*The Kingdom of Heaven*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9C9JvCXvbEkC&pg=PA81&dq=%22weigh+in+on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6ucuBj63RAhUGKGMKHVS0A6c4HhDoAQgzMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22weigh%20in%20on%22&f=false) (1996):

> Her knitting, then, which others choose to view as a compulsion, I choose to view rather as an expression of the choice she's freely made about herself. Its very extravagance, its oddity—the muffler, according to my kids, that is to say, *our* kids, is now the size of four school yards, incorporating eighty-eight shades of wool—this knitting's oddity, as I say, seems designed to skew the odds in favour of the life my ex-wife's living being her own life, rather than no one's, an attempt that is by my ex-wife to ***weigh in* on** the side of idiosyncrasy.

From Robert Pool, [*Beyond Engineering: How Society Shapes Technology*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BR1PQ6fPLz4C&pg=PT245&dq=%22weigh+in+on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ6fW1ia3RAhUNy2MKHT16C104FBDoAQgeMAE#v=onepage&q=%22weigh%20in%20on%22&f=false) (1997):

> On the other hand, courts are "responsive"—unlike the legislative or executive branches, which can ignore issues that don't seem important, courts must offer judgments on the items brought before them. This means that courts are often the first social institution to **weigh in on** a technology. Before legislatures pass their laws or regulatory agencies create their codes, the courts can be providing a rough, case-by-case control.

In all of these instances, the notion of "weighing in on" something amounts to expressing an opinion, presumably in the hope of tipping the scales in favor of one's favored views. But Google Books instances of "weighing in on" before 1994 invariably use the phrase in a nonfigurative sense—to describe standing on a scale in order to have one's weight measured. There seems to be a straight and not very long line between that sense and usage of the phrase and the figurative "state one's opinion" sense that makes its initial mark in Google Books results in the middle 1990s.